# TF-IDF score from TfIdfTransformer in sklearn on same word in two sentences with same frequency

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

If I have two sentences containing the same word, and this word appears with the same counts (frequency) in both sentences, why is the Tf-Idf score I get different for them?

Consider this list of texts:

```
data = [
    'Jumper in knit.',
    'A sweater in knit, black sweater.',
]
```

and consider that I fit and transform a `CountVectorizer` and a `TfIdfTransformer` on it, as in

```
count_vec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)

X_counts = count_vec.fit_transform(x_data_manual)
X_tfidf = tf_transformer.fit_transform(X_counts)
```

Then I print the features with their IDFs scores:

```
print zip(count_vec.get_feature_names(), tf_transformer.idf_)
```

obtaining

> [(u'black', 1.4054651081081644), (u'jumper', 1.4054651081081644), (u'knit', 1.0), (u'sweater', 1.4054651081081644)]

so we can see that all tokens have the same IDF except 'knit', all legit.

If I now ask for printing both the counts matrix and the TF-IDFs matrix,

```
print X_counts.todense()
print X_tfidf.todense()
```

what I get is, respectively

> [[0 1 1 0]
>    [1 0 1 2]]

(which is legit), and

> [[ 0.     0.815  0.58   0.   ]
>
> [ 0.426  0.     0.303  0.852]]

Now, I thought the TF-IDF score would be a multiplication of the term frequency (however calculated from the count/raw frequency) and the IDF, but I'm seeing 'knit' having a different score in the two sentences despite the frequencies are the same.

So what I'm missing/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is, after some more digging, that in the default configuration of the `TfIdfTransformer`, the scores get normalised in L2 norm at the end, per row.

In fact, the kwarg `norm` is documents in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html), but when reading I didn't properly understand what was being normalised, maybe a few more words would help.

A step by step explanation is reported [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

Comment: normalization is related to the elements number( max frequency ) in sentence, it could eliminate impact of long document